# How to get custom data out of generic principal inside an aspx code behind?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-4.5

I am building an application and integrating it with active directory.

So I authenticate my app user to active directory users, after that I store some of user's data like : `user group and user profile` to Generic principal and user identity to Generic identity.

My problem is I can't get user profile data from generic principal when I want to use it.

Can someone show me how to do that?

```
 string cookieName = FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName;
 HttpCookie authCookie = Context.Request.Cookies[cookieName];

 if (authCookie == null)
 {
       //There is no authentication cookie.
       return;
 }

 FormsAuthenticationTicket authTicket = null;

 try
 {
       authTicket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(authCookie.Value);
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
      //Write the exception to the Event Log.
       return;
 }

 if (authTicket == null)
 {
      //Cookie failed to decrypt.
      return;
 }

 String data = authTicket.UserData.Substring(0, authTicket.UserData.Length -1);
 string[] userProfileData =   data.Split(new char[] { '|' });
 //Create an Identity.
 GenericIdentity id = 
                  new GenericIdentity(authTicket.Name, "LdapAuthentication");
 //This principal flows throughout the request.
 GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(id, userProfileData);
 Context.User = principal;
```

Note : Code above is in global asax file, and I want to use user profile data which I stored in generic principal in another file named `default.aspx`.

Comment: We can't show you anything unless you show us how you are storing the data in generic principal in the first place.

Comment: I have edited my post with code, that is how i stored my data into generic principal, and that code is inside global asax file.

Comment: Ok. You're missing one more thing, `I can't get user profile data from generic principal when I want to use it.` => **When do you want to use it**? Inside an aspx page?

Comment: yep, i want to display user profile data in an aspx file called dafult.aspx, i want to put its code in page_load, this file called after user already authenticated.

Comment: @HendraLim Ok I added an answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

So first off you shouldn't be doing this:

```
GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(id, userProfileData);
                                                     //^^ this is wrong!!
```

The second argument to the constructor is for **Roles**. See the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.security.principal.genericprincipal.genericprincipal.aspx).

---

If you want to store data into the generic principal then what you should do is

1. Create a class out of `GenericIdentity` :

   ```
   class MyCustomIdentity : GenericIdentity
   {
     public string[] UserData { get; set;}
     public MyCustomIdentity(string a, string b) : base(a,b)
     {
     }
   }
   ```
2. Create it like this:

   ```
   MyCustomIdentity = 
              new MyCustomIdentity(authTicket.Name,"LdapAuthentication");
                                                     //fill the roles correctly.
   GenericPrincipal principal = new GenericPrincipal(id, new string[] {});
   ```
3. Get it in the page like this:

   The [Page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.web.ui.page.aspx) class has a [User](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/system.web.ui.page.user.aspx) property.

   So for example in Page load you could do this:

   ```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
     MyCustomIdentity id =  (MyCustomIdentity)this.User.Identity
     var iWantUserData = id.UserData;
    }
   ```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the following code:

```
FormsIdentity id = (FormsIdentity)HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
string userData = id.Ticket.UserData
```